# How do I install the old "add/remove applications"?

Tags: software-center

I have a netbook running Ubuntu. the Ubuntu Software Center is too slow and I like add/remove applications more than I do the Ubuntu Software Center. when I try fedora I like the add/remove applications but how do I get on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Synaptic Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/).

[image]

Which provides a thorough Package installation and Uninstallation option, with Sub-Menus such as Section, Origin, Status, Custom Filters, based on type of package/software.

But i will advise you to give another try to Ubuntu Software centre , you can explore it as here

[image]

You can Install and Uninstall quite Easily compared to Synaptic here, you just have to choose the right options as example in the screenshot , just expand them to see it.

Third option would be [apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) to remove and install packages.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you have only one alternative - the Terminal. It's really straightforward. Three commands or so and you're set to use it for adding/removing programs. Quick examples:

To install firefox:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

To remove firefox:

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

To install a program from external repository ("repo") first you need to add the repository. To install ppa:alexx2000/doublecmd repository :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexx2000/doublecmd
sudo apt-get update
```

I wouldn't recommend Synaptic manager. From my experience the risk of breaking your system is much higher when using Synaptic when compared to the Terminal (since you really limit your actions to copy/paste into Terminal anyway). 
If you try out many programs I'd recommend leaving the Software Center running. It's slowest when starting up for the first time after booting your system. After that it runs bearable. Give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily from

> Synaptic Package Manager

. To install it open a terminal & type  `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. Then run it from application menu. Click on status....search......"Right click" and select Full remove or similar option. Then click apply. Done.

Or you can uninstall your software by terminal. Tpne in a terminal

`sudo apt-get remove vlc` to remove **VLC**. Use correct name instead of `vlc`. example [**sudo apt-get remove firefox**]....to remove firefox from your system